Cloud TPU API enablement failed
I disabled the compute engine API while the cloud TPU API was running.
After that, I successfully reenabled the compute engine API. But when I tried to enable the cloud TPU API, I failed and got the following error message:
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.tpus.tpu-vm.list) The operation "operations/acf.p2-926693653212-038de011-eccb-4018-888e-9a6bea64a6a2" resulted in a failure: "[The enablement process failed for service 'tpu.googleapis.com'.
Help Token: AQAb6BwAfQtqAXvcUaRUCYRTP1L_OG7PXjtG4Sc7oEHZVWZ0XHEuJJ5E-JepKyy1-dIYbZF-MPEf-MHVG8LFt7rpMWRDbgakuLGftOR2RKtfPUrm] with failed services [tpu.googleapis.com]".
Details: "[<DetailsValueListEntry
additionalProperties: [<AdditionalProperty
key: '@type'
value: <JsonValue
string_value: 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.PreconditionFailure'>>, <AdditionalProperty
key: 'violations'
value: <JsonValue
array_value: <JsonArray
entries: [<JsonValue
object_value: <JsonObject
properties: [<Property
key: 'type'
value: <JsonValue
string_value: 'googleapis.com'>>, <Property
key: 'subject'
value: <JsonValue
string_value: '?error_code=160003&service=tpu.googleapis.com'>>]>>]>>>]>]".
